# Cache issue with poetry install in Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have 2 stages in a pipeline : Test and Build(dependent on Test). I am installing both Poetry and other dependencies on the test and build pipeline again. I want to reduce the time it takes for the CI pipeline to run. I came across this feature called cache, which will eliminate the need to run the same scripts in the build pipeline again. Can someone please help me by rewriting the attached yaml. I am very new to this.

```
pr: 
    - main

pool:
    vmImage: ubuntu-latest

variables:
    python_version: "3.10"
    package_name: "hatutu"
    notebooks_location: "notebooks"

stages:
- stage: Test
  jobs:
      - job: Test
        displayName: Test
        steps:
            - task: UsePythonVersion@0
              inputs:
                  versionSpec: '$(python_version)'
              displayName: 'Use Python $(python_version)'

            - script: |
                  curl -sSL https://install.python-poetry.org | python3 - --version=1.5.1
                  echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=PATH]${PATH}:${HOME}/.poetry/bin"
              displayName: 'Install Poetry'

            - script: make install
              displayName: 'Install dependencies'

            - script: |
                  echo "y
                  $(WORKSPACE_REGION_URL)
                  $(DATABRICKS_PAT)
                  $(EXISTING_CLUSTER_ID)
                  $(WORKSPACE_ORG_ID)
                  15001" | poetry run databricks-connect configure
              displayName: 'Configure DBConnect'

            - script: make ci-test
              displayName: 'Run tests'

            - task: PublishTestResults@2
              condition: succeededOrFailed()
              inputs:
                  testResultsFiles: 'test-output/test-*.xml'
              displayName: 'Publish test results'

            - task: PublishCodeCoverageResults@1
              condition: succeededOrFailed()
              inputs:
                  codeCoverageTool: 'cobertura'
                  summaryFileLocation: 'test-output/coverage.xml'
                  pathToSources: '$(package_name)'

            - script: make ci-lint-flake8
              condition: succeededOrFailed()
              displayName: 'Run Flake8 linter'

            - script: make ci-lint-mypy
              condition: succeededOrFailed()
              displayName: 'Run mypy linter'

            - task: PublishTestResults@2
              condition: succeededOrFailed()
              inputs:
                  testResultsFiles: 'test-output/lint-*.xml'
              displayName: 'Publish linting results'

- stage: Build
  dependsOn: Test
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/main'))
  jobs:
      - job: Build
        displayName: Build
        steps:
            - task: UsePythonVersion@0
              inputs:
                  versionSpec: '$(python_version)'
              displayName: 'Use Python $(python_version)'

            - script: |
                  curl -sSL https://install.python-poetry.org | python3 - --version=1.5.1
                  echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=PATH]${PATH}:${HOME}/.poetry/bin"
              displayName: 'Install Poetry'

            - script: make install
              displayName: 'Install dependencies'

            - script: make build
              displayName: "Build Package"

            - script: |
                  poetry config repositories.azure https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/$(ORGANIZATION)/_packaging/$(ARTIFACT_FEED)/pypi/upload
                  poetry config http-basic.azure $(AZD_USER) $(AZD_PAT)
                  poetry publish -r azure
              displayName: Publish to $(ARTIFACT_FEED)

            - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
              displayName: 'Deploy Notebooks'
              inputs:
                  PathtoPublish: $(notebooks_location)
                  ArtifactName: hatutu-notebooks
```

Comment: You would need to run the installation of poetry and other dependencies provided that you are considering using different jobs for "Build" and "Test" (Since each job runs on a fresh agent in the agent pool). This can be restructured into a single job which can drastically reduce the time for your pipeline run.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to keep Test and Build in separate stages. They should be part of the same job.

> A stage is a logical boundary in the pipeline. It can be used to mark separation of concerns (for example, Build, QA, and production). Each stage contains one or more jobs. When you define multiple stages in a pipeline, by default, they run one after the other. You can specify the conditions for when a stage runs. When you are thinking about whether you need a stage, ask yourself:
>
> - Do separate groups manage different parts of this pipeline? For example, you could have a test manager that manages the jobs that relate to testing and a different manager that manages jobs related to production deployment. In this case, it makes sense to have separate stages for testing and production.
> - Is there a set of approvals that are connected to a specific job or set of jobs? If so, you can use stages to break your jobs into logical groups that require approvals.
> - Are there jobs that need to run a long time? If you have part of your pipeline that will have an extended run time, it makes sense to divide them into their own stage.

Link to documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/get-started/key-pipelines-concepts?view=azure-devops)

So if you goal is just to speed up pipeline you should join stages. I would go with separate stage just for deploy, but even then test, build and create package for deploy I would put in one stage.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately this is not something I can change as this is from my customer's pipeline. Only thing I can do is try to optimize the process.